# Changing javascript eval method to another solution

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, eval

I try to get rid of an ugly javscript eval method (Cause we all know it is unsecure).
I have the following problem. I build a dynamic searchstring.
Depends on the TLD a user decided to search for.

Here is my code:

```
 if (tld == 0) {
            var searchString = 'value.tld != ""';
        }
        if (tld == 1) {
            var searchString = 'value.tld == "de"';
        }
        if (tld == 2) {
            var searchString = 'value.tld == "com" || value.tld == "net" || value.tld == "org" || value.tld == "info" || value.tld == "biz"';
        }
        if (tld == 3) {
            var searchString = 'value.tld == "io"';
        }
```

Depending on the search parameter 'searchstring', I build this routine with eval:

```
if (eval(searchString)) {
    // Do something special, depends on the tld variable
}
```

How can i rebuild this without using 'eval'. The premission is, that the first part of the code is beeing untouched.

Thanks in advance

Nick

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't change the first part of your code? Having the conditions as strings is going to be problematic and difficult to deal with if they need to be evaluated.

Comment: Actually, there a a couple of reasons here, why I can not change the first part of the script.

Comment: Are the operators you need limited to what is above?  And, what are you translating this to?  (I'm debating in my head between suggesting you make a lightweight parser to handle this use case, or to suggest you sandbox real JavaScript to actually eval the string in a better way.)

Comment: Later on, the operators can be up to 1057 different TLD's. And groups of TLDs also. So there can "drop in" a lot of TLD's later.

Comment: @Brad - But the parser is an intersting way, I also started to think about now ;-)

Comment: By operators, I mean `==`, `||`, `!=`, etc.  I think how you do this depends on what you do with the query structure later, and what's required to be supported.  It would be trivial, for example, to parse what you have now with RegEx.  But, if it gets much more complicated or if you need to support actual script, that's different.

Comment: I see. Of course. (It's to  early in the morning here...) 
At least it is limited to the shown operators: ==, || and One time !=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
let choices = {
  1: ['de'],
  2: ['com', 'net', 'org', 'info', 'biz'],
  3: ['io']
};

function check(tldparam) {
  if (tld === 0) {
     return value.tld !== "";
  } else {
    return tld === tldparam && choices[tldparam].includes(value.tld);
  }
}
```

And we test it like:

```
// Got this value from somewhere
let tld = 2;
let value = {tld: 'net'};

// This is my checking criterion
let tldparam = 2;

if (check(tldparam)) {
    // Do something special, depends on the tld variable
}
```

Does it serve your purpose?

Comment: Haha, yes (thumb up). This is what I also figured out myself... (Building an Array). But your solution is quite a little bit better than mine. Assuming that everything is really better than using 'eval'

Comment: Yes, in fact, you should seriously do some refactoring of this code, otherwise, soon the array will be a mess, and the smart `check` function will have more if..else blocks. ;)